# Enable ViewPort Zooming: MS Visual Studio 2013 Update5, Corodova, Android

Tags: android, mobile, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-cordova

I am developing mobile app on Visual Studio Using Cordova.

I want to add the zoom feature to the application.Please help to with step by step process to add it.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Updated question along with tag

Answer (score 0):

Typically this is controlled by the viewport tag.  The default template includes a viewport designed for typical scenarios where you do not want zooming.  See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag for information on how to configure it to meet your needs.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I tried this solution but didn't work until i added the plugin: https://github.com/kumbe/Phonegap-ZoomControl.git